# MPCHART YAxis are showing incorrect labels

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

> My MPCHART of the YAxis labels are not fitting according to arraylist i provided and doesn't allign with the stacked horizontal bar chart?

> shift Labels are not showing and not aligning with the horizontal stacked  bar chart

```
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setNoDataText("No data available here !");
    chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(40);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);

    chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    chart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);

    // change the position of the y-labels
    chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(true);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setTypeface(Utils.setFont(SingleEquipmentDashboard.this));
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(arrayListHour.size());
    rightAxis.setGranularity(1f);
```

> getFromTime contains utc time which is converted to float time

```
    if (data.getCurrentShiftDowntimes().size() > 0) {
        float temp = Utils.getShiftChartTime("", data.getCurrentShiftDowntimes().get(0).getFromTime());
        if (temp > 0) {
            rightAxis.calculate(temp, chart.getYMax() + temp);
            chart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(temp, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        }
    }
```

> The **MAIN** problem is there that the values are not formatted to the right position

```
    rightAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            if (value <= -1) {
                /*Display positive Hours number in Previous date chart*/
                value = 24 + value;
            }
            if (value >= 24) {
                value = value - 24;
            }
          
            return String.format("%02d", (int) value);
        }
    });
    chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
    Legend l = chart.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(false);
    chart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can Use set value formatted as Below

```
rightAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(youraArrayListAsLabels));
```